# Connection Timeout MongoDB, AWS lambda and Nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

I am facing a weird issue. I have MongoDB installed and working on a project on an EC2 instance. I tried to access the DB from local it is working fine. But, when I try to execute my AWS lambda function I get a timeout error. So increased the lambda function timeout to 50seconds. I am running a simple query to find one record of 10 records. And I am getting the following error. Can anyone help me with this?

```
MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [EC2_PUBLIC_IP:PORT_NUMBER] on first connect [MongoNetworkError: connection 0 to EC2_PUBLIC_IP:PORT_NUMBER timed out]
```

I am using [MONGODB-NATIVE](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native) with Nodejs.

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

MongoClient.connect(DB_URL, (err, conn) => {
  if(err) return console.error(err);

  let db = conn.db('DB_NAME');

  db.collection('COLLECTION_NAME').findOne({ value: 1232131 }, (error,results) => {
    if(error) return console.error(error);

    conn.close();
    return console.log(results);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think this is an issue with your code. This is an off-topic question as it's a problem with your firewall settings.

In the EC2 security groups please add MongoDB port in inbound ports that default to 27017 and then try to access the db.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I added the port in Inbounds of ec2 security group, and it started working.

Answer (score 1):

The first answer alone didn't work for me, I still had to port forward to my mongo replica

This is the command you want to run.

```
"ssh -i aws-ssh-key.pem -g -N -f -L 8000:127.0.0.1:27017 ec2-user@10.0.8.10"
```

checkout this link for details on the command.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/64890853/9206157

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable