# MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

**I'm trying to connect my remote EC2 mongodb but it's saying MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED awsip:27017**

In aws mongodb config file I change bindIp to 0.0.0.0 but I didn't change the security section.

This is an express application I have try to connect 2 way with aws mongodb and the both way I got the same error, here is my db setup:

```
Setup: 01

const DATABASE_URL = `mongodb://${cfg.dbUser}:${cfg.dbPass}@${cfg.dbHost}:${cfg.dbPort}/${cfg.dbName}`

server.listen(port, () => {
  mongoose.connect(DATABASE_URL,
    {
      // auth: {
      //   user: cfg.dbUser,
      //   password: cfg.dbPass
      // },
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
    })
    .then(() => {
      console.log("[  ] AWS MongoDB database connected.");
      console.log(`[ Server ] waiting on: ${cfg.serverHost}:${port}`);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(
        "[  ] Database connection error",
        { Error: err }
      );
    })
});


Setup: 02

const DATABASE_URL = `mongodb://${cfg.dbHost}:${cfg.dbPort}/${cfg.dbName}`
server.listen(port, () => {
  mongoose.connect(DATABASE_URL,
    {
      auth: {
        user: cfg.dbUser,
        password: cfg.dbPass
      },
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
    })
    .then(() => {
      console.log("[  ] AWS MongoDB database connected.");
      console.log(`[ Server ] waiting on: ${cfg.serverHost}:${port}`);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(
        "[  ] Database connection error",
        { Error: err }
      );
    })
});
```

**I have created database in aws and all the database user permission credential.**

***I'm using dotenv to load all the aws credintial***

Also the same problem when I'm trying to connect with MongoDB-Compass from my machine.

```
connect ECONNREFUSED awsip:27017
```

Here is my terminal picture
[image]

***Hope expert will help me.***

Comment: Have you allowed inbound security access to the mongodb security group?

Comment: Yes, I have. Sorry, I forgot to mention it.

Comment: How do both servers security groups look like?

Comment: Okay, I can share with you my security group.

Custom TCP TCP 27017 0.0.0.0/0 -
Custom TCP TCP 27017 ::/0 -

Comment: And the other instance has `sg-0e50606f1947c167c` attached to it?

Comment: No no no, I miss first time. That was another security group

Comment: Does it work to connect via private IP rather than public IP?

Comment: I'm trying with public IP

Comment: So what about the private IP?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217371/discussion-between-chris-williams-and-as-md-habibullah).

Comment: Get the connection working with `mongo` shell before involving your application.

Answer (score 1):

The solution to this is ssh port forwarding.

First make sure you can ssh into your mongo instance server and access your primary and secondary replica Nodes

Then create a new inbound rule for your security group with these setups on the mongo server with a public IPv4 address

1. Custom TCP 8000 0.0.0.0/0
2. Custom TCP 8000 ::/0

For the port forwarding part

SSH Port forwarding (SSH tunnel) creates a connection between a port on your current machine to a port on another server

here is an example

```
ssh -i aws-ssh-key.pem -g -N -f -L 8000:127.0.0.1:27017 ec2-user@10.0.8.10
```

when you initiate this command, what it does is open and connect a local port from the current machine 8000 to your mongo server:port 127.0.0.1:27017 with the username and address ec2-user@10.0.8.10

for the flags *-g, -N, -f, -L*

*-g* Allows remote hosts to connect to local forwarded ports.

*-N* Do not execute a remote command. to prevent ssh from opening a shell on the server

*-f* to run ssh in the background.

*-L* specify local port to use

Run this command to list the process

```
ps aux | grep ssh
```

Run this command to kill the process anytime

```
kill -9 <pid>
```

I hope this answers your question for more references

https://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JKrO5WABdoY

https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2020/02/05/connect-to-remote-mongodb-on-aws-ec2-simply-and-securely-via-ssh-tunnel